# Accessing a string by index vs advancing a pointer

Tags: c

Suppose I have a function to join a list of strings:

For example:

```
void join_strings(char * joined_string_buffer, char ** src, char * separator)
```

And it could be called like:

```
join_strings(buffer, ["one", "two", NULL], "--");
printf("%s", buffer);
// "one--two"
```

I've written the function and it works using the following:

```
void join_strings(char * joined_string_buffer, char ** src, char * separator) {

    size_t sep_len = strlen(separator);

    int idx = 0;

    while (*src) {
        size_t string_len = strlen(*src);
        for (char *p= *src++; *p; p++)
            joined_string_buffer[idx++] = *p;
        for (int i=0; i<sep_len; i++)
            joined_string_buffer[idx++] = separator[i];
    }
    joined_string_buffer[idx] = '\0';

}
```

My questions is why does this work:

```
for (int i=0; i<sep_len; i++)
    joined_string_buffer[idx++] = separator[i];
```

But this doesn't:

```
for (int i=0; i<sep_len; i++)
    *joined_string_buffer++ = separator[i];
```

Why can't I just keep advancing the pointer in the character array and copy over each character? What's the difference between the first and second way of doing it?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question, but did you also change all other lines that used `idx`? You might want to post the complete version of the code that does not work.

Comment: @jamesdlin sure -- which line/part do you mean and I can make sure.

Comment: The second one moves `joined_string_buffer` forward, maybe you have a mistake later in the code when you assume it still had its original value

Comment: @TagC198 Post the complete version of your `join_strings` function where you've modified it to use pointers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep advancing the pointer in the second "for" loop but you need to ensure that the pointer is appropriately 'advanced' in the previous "for" loop as well.
So the code would be....

```
while (*src) {
    size_t string_len = strlen(*src);
    for (char *p= *src++; *p; p++){
       //joined_string_buffer[idx++] = *p; not using index addressing
       *joined_string_buffer++ = *p;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<sep_len; i++){
         //joined_string_buffer[idx++] = separator[i];//not using index addressing
         *joined_string_buffer++ = separator[i];

    }
}

*joined_string_buffer = '\0';
```